# Forcing Genymotion network traffic to pass through Ubuntu proxy settings

Tags: networking, virtualbox, android, proxy, emulation

On a Genymotion virtual device (Android 6.0.0 API 23) I need it to follow the network proxy rules of Ubuntu which are set in **Settings --> Network --> Network proxy**. I tried on both enabled "**apply system wide**" and without that, but have not met the purpose.

Since Genymotion uses **VirtualBox** to run emulators, I changed *Network* settings of the virtual machine in the VirtualBox application.But here's what's going on:

- While the emulator is running, any change in the VM's settings makes the UI frozen and prevent interacting with the emulator.
- When the emulator is disabled and Network Settings on *VirtualBox* update, Genymotion discard changes on start and run the emulator with its default settings.

These are default settings in VirtualBox (Adpater1, Adapter2):

[image: Adapter1]

[image: Adapter2]

Answer (score 1):

Changing any setting on VirtualBox instance on "Adapter 1" will indeed freeze the UI.

You actually have to set the proxy settings inside the emulator himself, on the Android Wifi Settings.
This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. Does it work with Ubuntu's local HTTP proxy address? i.e `127.0.0.1:port`